# Maxima doesn't find a solution for diff eq with desolve

Tags: differential-equations, maxima, computer-algebra-systems

During my exercise with wxmaxima 11.08.0 (ubuntu 12.04, Maxima version: 5.24.0)
I followed an [example from P.Lutus](http://arachnoid.com/maxima/differential_equations.html) and his second example didn't work for me.

```
eq: y(t) = -r*c*'diff(y(t),t)+m*sin(%omega*t);
sol:desolve( eq, y(t) );
Is  %omega  zero or nonzero? nonzero
```

then Maxima isn't reacting anymore until I restart it.
Is there something changed in maxima that I need to activate or define first to get the result ?

The expected output should be: 
[image: Intermediate result]

There is a second part of my question in case I define the equation by hand:

```
sol: y(t) = (m * sin(%omega*t))              / (%omega^2*c^2*r^2 + 1) - 
            (%omega*c*m*r*cos(%omega*t))     / (%omega^2*c^2*r^2 + 1) +
            (%omega*c*m*r*%e^-((1*t)/(c*r))) / (%omega^2*c^2*r^2 + 1);
```

Initial conditions for a continuous process:

```
init_val:-(c*m*r*(%e^-(t/r*c))*%omega)/(c^2*r^2*%omega^2+1); 
atvalue(y(t),t=0, init_val);
try2 : desolve(sol,y(t));
"Is  "%omega"  zero or nonzero?" nonzero;
```

[image: last term still there]

Here the last term is still there. Are these problems based on the use of trigonometric functions ?

Best regards,
Marcus

I updated via PPA to wxMaxima 13.04.0 & Maxima 5.29.1. Now desolve fnished, but the last term seems very complicated.
[image: maxima 5.29.1 desolve result]

Doing the init_val with the negativ last term and desolve command still leaves the %e^(..)*... in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get more interest in this question on the Maxima mailing list. See: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/maximalist.html

For the first version of Lutus example 2, I get:

```
y(t) = m*sin(%omega*t)/(%omega^2*c^2*r^2+1)
 -%omega*c*m*r*cos(%omega*t)/(%omega^2*c^2*r^2+1)
 +(y(0)*%omega^2*c^3*r^3+%omega*c^2*m*r^2+y(0)*c*r)*%e^-(t/(c*r))
  /(c*r*(%omega^2*c^2*r^2+1))$
```

which is the same as the expected result, if y(0) = 0. However, I don't see where that is assumed.

After `atvalue(y(t),t=0,init_val)`, I get the same result as Lutus, namely:

```
y(t) = m*sin(%omega*t)/(%omega^2*c^2*r^2+1)
 -%omega*c*m*r*cos(%omega*t)/(%omega^2*c^2*r^2+1)$
```

I am working with Maxima 5.31.1, built with Clisp, on Linux.

Comment: I tried a compiled version of Maxima 5.31.2, build with clisp (Ubuntu 12.04 repro). The results are the same as under version 5.29.1, I send a message to the mailing list. Regards